# Issues using Starscream with the Poloniex WAMP API

Tags: ios, swift, poloniex, starscream

I'm trying to use [Starscream](https://github.com/daltoniam/Starscream) (which is great) to connect to the [Poloniex](https://m.poloniex.com/support/api/) (cryptocurrency exchange) API to retrieve live quotes for prices over socket connection.

I have been successful using [Autobahn](https://github.com/crossbario/autobahn-python), in connecting and subscribing in Python.

Now on iOS I'm having trouble (using Swift).

This is how I'm preparing the socket.

```
self.socket = WebSocket(url: URL(string: "wss://api.poloniex.com")!, protocols: ["ticker"])
```

However, I get a disconnect delegate call with the error:

```
(Error Domain=WebSocket Code=400 "Invalid HTTP upgrade" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Invalid HTTP upgrade}
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Is this the correct way to subscribe using Starscream?

Help appreciated.

John

Comment: did you figure out what was causing this issue?

Comment: does this help? https://github.com/daltoniam/Starscream/issues/397

Comment: I am trying to do the same thing and getting the same error

Comment: @Nevin in the end I was able to fix it. I needed to use Swamp, not starscream!